# Fluid force on a surface

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Since the hydrostatic force done on a surface is calculated by integrating the pressure of fluid times the surface element, we realize that its directed normal to the surface. Now this explains "mathematically" the reason why its being normal to the surface. But intuitively, I'm still not convinced. In case, for example, we had a horizontal surface and the force were directed oblique on it, why should it leak out of it vertically and not oblique?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword is *hydrostatic* force. By definition, a fluid flows in the presence of a shear/tangential force, so, if the fluid is assumed to be static, there can not be such force: therefore, a hydrostatic force must be normal to the surface.

Comment: Thank u . The reason I had the confusion is that we solved a problem which we had a door situated in an oblique way and above it , there's a static force that has a vertically downward direction(due to the difference of pressure between above and below) . The question was to find the hydrostatic force done on the surface of the door. We only brought the normal component of the force . But intuitively I've found that the door must follow the original direction of the fluid force , that is moving vertically downward (along the gravity force) and not just normal to the surface. I'm confused.

Comment: @ZahraaKhalife, it's subtle. You might want to make your comment into a new question, but I can already tell you that the answer has to do with modeling: 1) if you model the door a 2D object, a sheet, it has no volume, and it'll feel no buoying force on it (the pressure from both sides have identical magnitudes and cancel out); 2) if the door is considered a 3D object, then you have a parallelepiped and the sum of all pressure forces will point upwards.

Comment: Ah I see. Now the door was a 2D object . And there was no fluid below it just above it .